# RXJava pass a value into onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using RXJava 2. After some logic in `subscribe` method I want to remove an used file. I guess I should do that in `onComplete`. But I can not pass there my `File` object.
My code:
Questions:

```
Observer<Bitmap> observer = new Observer<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(mImageView.getTag().toString().equals(TAG)) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        //            outputFile.delete();
    }
};

Observable<Bitmap> observable = Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<Bitmap> e) throws Exception {
        File outputFile = new File(newTAG);
        // do some stuff with a file
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUrl(newTAG, width, height);
        e.onNext(bitmap);
        // now I need to delete a file
        e.onComplete();
        }
    }
);
observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(observer);
```

1. How to pass a `outputFile` into `onComplete`?
2. Is there a way to create observable and subscride it in one event or in a less amount of code?

Comment: 1) use tuple types and store the file in your observer. 2) you can factor out the common code into methods but otherwise you always have 1 instance created for the Observable and 1 for the Observer.

Comment: If I delete my file inside onComplete method will it execute in a main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't pass Object to `onComplete()`, as `onComplete()` doesn't have values, that is a signal the the streams ends, and no more items will be emitted.
   you can pass it at `onNext()` with each emission (i.e. wrap the 2 objects with tuple like @akarnokd suggested) and delete it there.
2. you can simply write all the code continuously with anonymous methods, and if you will use lambdas it will cut out more boiler-plate code.
3. if you will delete the file at the `onCompleted` it will indeed will be executed at main thread, as you specify it by `observerOn()`.

Anyhow, you don't have to do it on the `onCompleted()` event, just delete it on the subscription code (create method) after you've extracted the Bitmap to memory, the subscriber shouldn't know or care about how the `Bitmap` extracted. moreover you can use `fromCallable()`,meaning wrap it with method that do all the operations. to sum it up:

```
 Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        File outputFile = new File(newTAG);
        // do some stuff with a file
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUrl(newTAG, width, height);
        // be sure to handle properly exceptions for ensure file will be closed
        outputFile.delete();
        return bitmap;
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(bitmap -> {
                        if (mImageView.getTag().toString().equals(TAG)) {
                            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        //handle error
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use interface instead of perform operation in onComplete() or onNext().

Create Interface

```
public interface OnActionComplete {
    void onComplete();
}
```

Implement it in your Activity or Fragment

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnActionComplete {
    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        //perform your action
    }
}
```

Now Just call that Method on completion of your task like onNext.

```
@Override
public void onNext(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(mImageView.getTag().toString().equals(TAG)) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        activityInstance.onComplete(); // this will trigger onComplete() method of interface.
    }
}
```